# Controling The Larynx When Singing

Tags: technique, vocal-cords

I have been told before that one should keep their larynx (is that the adam's apple area???) neutral when singing. Whenever I start to sing, my adam's apple moves up and down depending on the pitch. Especially when i sing higher, it is beyond control. How do I keep it neutral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple means to get aware of what your larynx is doing is lightly touching two fingers to its side while singing.

Relaxing it while singing takes practice.  Don't expect significant progress in weeks.

Comment: Yes. I can feel it but i can't control it.

Comment: You don't want to "control" it, you want to relax it. It's normal for it to go up and down a little bit. But if you're straining when you sing high notes, you are probably squeezing and pushing it high. The key is good breath support. Then you don't need to strain, you can relax your throat, and your larynx will naturally be lower.

Answer (score 6):

This is something that cannot be adequately explained in writing. In order to learn to do this correctly, I think it is necessary for you to take voice lessons with a good voice teacher. As you sing, your voice teacher can give you immediate feedback on what you are doing, so that you can gradually learn to control the position of your larynx, mouth, throat, soft palate, and all the other parts of your body involved in singing.

And no, observing the movement of your adam's apple doesn't really provide helpful information. It is quite a bit more complicated than that. But with some lessons, you can learn all this so that it becomes "second nature" and you don't have to think about it all the time. This is similar to the process of learning to play any musical instrument. At first you have to think about an enormous number of different factors in producing a good musical tone, and it seems daunting. But with practice, all these factors become ingrained and you can do them without too much self-analysis. It simply takes practice.

I will give you one verbal description or analogy that I have heard several voice teachers use:

Yawn. Yawn a big, full yawn. Open your mouth wide and drop your jaw all the way down. Feel how open your throat feels, and how much space you create inside your throat when you yawn. Your larynx moves downward to open up this space.

Whenever you feel that your singing voice is tense or strained, stop and yawn, and feel what it feels like to have all that open space in there. This is the proper position for relaxed singing without strain. Obviously, when you sing, you can't keep your jaw all the way down and your mouth all the way open; the point of the exercise is to learn to create all that open space and to recognize what it feels like.

Now imagine that you have a tangerine or a small orange stuck in the back of your throat (not literally, because that would probably kill you!). Feel the amount of space that you have to open up in the back of your throat to make room for that tangerine. Again, every time you start to sing a phrase, try to make that amount of space open up in your throat. This also means that your larynx has moved down.

It is quite easy to sing with the larynx in the down position when you are singing low notes. As you sing notes higher and higher in pitch, your tendency is to raise the position of the larynx. But you can learn to sing high notes while your larynx is in the down position, and you will learn that this produces a better, fuller vocal sound with less strain.

This will get you started, but I still encourage you to find a voice teacher and take some lessons.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend practice. Believe it or not, I just viewed this so I can get better a singing less than 10 minutes ago as of writing this and somehow, I already mastered it and I noticed the improvements right away.

Comment: I think OP is ultimately asking HOW to practice. I think we all intuitively know we should practice, don't we?